# How do I cast a String to a Long-int in C?

Tags: c, string, linked-list, dynamic-programming, long-integer

How do i turn a String in C to a Long integer, without removing the leading zero?

I have used both sscanf() and strtol() functions but they both remove the leading zero as if its white-space.  I have tried chatgpt and bard for a solution but none of theirs work at all.

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>

   int main()
   {
       char *num = "09999999991";

       long n = strtol(num, NULL, 10);;

       printf("%ld\n", n); 
    
       /*
           Output: 9999999991 
           Expected: 09999999991
       */ 
   }
```

I'am origanally getting the numbers from two linked lists converting them to longs so that i can get the sum and make a new linked list out of the sum like bellow

```
    struct ListNode *addTwoNumbers(struct ListNode * l1, struct ListNode * l2)
    {
        // make two string to hold the nums
        char num1[500] = "";
        char num2[500] = "";

        long long n1, n2, sum, reverse1 = 0, reverse2 = 0, remainder;

        // get the first num
        struct ListNode *tmp = l1;
        while (tmp != NULL)
        {
            char c[600];
            sprintf(c, "%lld", tmp->val);
            strcat(num1, c);
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }

        // get the second num
        tmp = l2;
        while (tmp != NULL)
        {
            char c[600];
            sprintf(c, "%lld", tmp->val);
            strcat(num2, c);
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
        printf("%s + %s\n", num1, num2);

        // cast to int
        n1 = strtol(num1, NULL, 10);
        n2 = strtol(num2, NULL, 10);
        printf("%lld + %lld\n", n1, n2);

        // reverse the numbers
        while (n1 != 0)
        {
            remainder = n1 % 10;
            reverse1 = reverse1 * 10 + remainder;
            n1 /= 10;
        }
        while (n2 != 0)
        {
            remainder = n2 % 10;
            reverse2 = reverse2 * 10 + remainder;
            n2 /= 10;
        }

        printf("%lld + %lld\n", reverse1, reverse2);

        // get the sum
        sum = reverse1 + reverse2;

        printf("%ld\n", sum);
        char value[500];
        sprintf(value, "%ld", sum);

        struct ListNode *head = NULL;
        for (int i = 0, len = strlen(value); i < len; i++)
        {
            struct ListNode *n = malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
            if (n == NULL)
            {
                exit(1);
            }

            n->val = value[i] - '0';
            n->next = NULL;

            n->next = head;
            head = n;
        }

        // free memory
        tmp = l1;
        while (tmp != NULL)
        {
            struct ListNode *next = tmp->next;
            free(tmp);
            tmp = next;
        }

        tmp = l2;
        while (tmp != NULL)
        {
            struct ListNode *next = tmp->next;
            free(tmp);
            tmp = next;
        }

        return head;
    }
```

Comment: The leading zero has no significance for a long int. That is strictly a formatting issue for display - it has no impact on what the long int actually represents. You can add leading zeros in your output if desired. Integers are numeric types; they do numeric things. The leading zero doesn't change the numeric behavior of the type. If you look at the memory occupied by the long int, you'll see that it **actually does** include zeros for the unused bits within the size of the type. `printf` just doesn't include leading zeros by default.

Comment: The answer provided answers the question you pose about leading 0's. But you seem to have questions about how to add big numbers. Can you ask a different question, illustrating what you are trying to do, and the algorithm you are trying to follow?

Comment: I need to do math with it like so: ``` str1 = "086568357" str2 = "678085897" // Reverse the strings rstr1 = "753865680" rstr2 = "798580876" //Convert them to longs long_num1 = 753865680 long_num2 = 798580876 // and then get the sum. sum = long_num1 + long_num2 ``` but the leading zero gets removed and it makes the calculation all wrong

Comment: Perhaps another strategy would be appropriate?

Comment: that's what I am trying to do. I have been trying to solve this for about 5 hours now but can't figure it out.

Comment: You'll need to reverse the string (working with it as a `char` array) *before* converting it to an integer.  "Reverse" isn't really an arithmetic operation, since it depends not only on what the number actually *is*, but also how it's written.

Comment: As an example: say Alice has thirteen apples.  That could be written as 13, or 013, or 0000013, but they are all the same number thirteen.  What do you get when you reverse the number of apples that Alice has?  Do you get 31 (one), or 310, or 3100000?  It's not a question you can answer just by knowing the number of apples that she has.  So you can't solve it by operating on a `long int` (which only represents what the number *is*); you have to use a string (which represents *how it is written*).

Comment: This is not a 'cast'. It is a type conversion.

Comment: so it's best that I reverse the string as a string and then convert it to a long number

Comment: well it did solve it to reverse the strings first and then convert to long and the code passes 1556 cases of 1558 i think am okay with that. and maybe I will try switching to Python cuz I saw someone else doing what I did in 15 lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... getting the numbers from two linked lists converting them to longs so that i can get the sum ...

Instead of converting to `long`, adding and converting back to a *string*, consider simply *adding* the string content.

The below finds the string size potentially needed, allocates, then adds, just like we learned in our early school days, finds the sum one digit at a time.  We start with the least significant digit.

```
// Untested illustrative code

#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// Return an allocated string of the sum of the strings.
// Return NULL on problems: out-of-memory, non-numeric text.
char* string_sum(const char *a, const char *b) {
  const char *s;

  // Test for digits only and find length
  for (s = a; *s; s++) {
    if (!isdigit(*(const unsigned char* )s)) {
      return NULL;
    }
  }
  size_t a_len = (size_t) (s - a);

  for (s = b; *s; s++) {
    if (!isdigit(*(const unsigned char* )s)) {
      return NULL;
    }
  }
  size_t b_len = (size_t) (s - b);

  // Allocate 
  size_t c_len = a_len > b_len ? a_len : b_len;
  c_len++; // +1 for potential carry.
  size_t c_size = c_len + 1 /* null character */;
  char *c = malloc(c_size);
  if (c == NULL) {
    return NULL;
  }
  c[c_len] = '\0';

  // Add digits, starting with least.
  int carry = 0;
  while (a_len > 0 || b_len > 0 || carry) {
    int sum = carry;
    if (a_len > 0) {
      sum += a[--a_len] - '0';
    }
    if (b_len > 0) {
      sum += b[--b_len] - '0';
    }
    c[--c_len] = (char) ('0' + sum % 10);
    carry = sum / 10;
  }

  // Adjust for carry and return.
  return memmove(c, c + c_len, c_size - c_len);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the leading zero of your expected output.  `long` stores the a number 9999999991.  The token `09999999991`, btw, is in invalid octal constant.

If you want to format the number padded with 0 to 11 digits you can use the format string `"%011ld\n"`.  As you already have the string you could you do it at run-time like this:

```
#include <string.h>
// ...
printf("%0*ld\n", (int) strlen(num), n);
```

Comment: yes, but I don't want to print the number I need to do math with it like so: 

```
   str1 = "086568357" 
   str2 = "678085897"

   // Reverse the strings
   rstr1 = "753865680"
   rstr2 = "798580876"

   //Convert them to longs 
   long_num1 = 753865680
   long_num2 = 798580876

   // and then get the sum
   sum = long_num1 + long_num2
```
but the leading zero gets removed and it makes the calculation all wrong

Comment: Then reverse the string before doing the (long) addition.  Or do the addition using the strings (see @chux-ReinstateMonica answer below) and don't convert them to long.